# Can we set form tag in master page as well as aspx page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms, master-pages

I getting the error i.e. a page can have only one server-side form tag.
I know the solution of this error, that if I remove the one of the form tag from master page or aspx page then this error will remove. But I want to use form tag in both form i.e. master page and simple aspx form. Because .net tools I am using in master page as well as in aspx page. So, to run the .net tools we want to create under form which is runat="server". But by doing this it shows the below error. Please give me some hint or any solution to solve this issues. Thank You.

Comment: You can only have one form with the `runat="server"` attribute. Therefore it belongs in the master page, not in the content page. There is no reason to have two. Think about it, the content page gets merged with the master page when it's rendered anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one form tag , ideally form tag in the master page will be suffice . Can you tell us why you need form tag in aspx page ? Please share the code that will help us to get the work around for your use case.